# books of n-ary groups

Tags: gr.group-theory

Tell me, please, where can I find books on n-ary groups.

Comment: A. M. Galmak, n-ary groups. You can find it at 
http://arxiv.org/abs/1111.7191

Comment: Thank you, but I know this book. I would like to read the other works